# Will My Dispose Methods Get Called at End of ASP.NET Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a lightweight class I use to keep keep track of who the user is in an ASP.NET MVC web request. It retrieves a dictionary from application cache and reads and modifies some values, and at the end of each method where the cached dictionary is accessed, inserts the dictionary back into cache.

I would like to just be able to modify the dictionary, and have it inserted back into cache at the end of the web request by implementing IDisposable. Will ASP.NET call Dispose on every  object that was created in the course of the request, or do I need to handle this manually in the application's end request event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ASP.NET will not call the `Dispose` method on any instance.  You will need to handle this either with a `using` statement or by manually calling `Dispose` on the instance.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me if a dictionary retrieved from the cache is a reference or a copy? Because if it's a reference, then I don't even need to insert if back, right?

Comment: OK, the reference thing was a silly question, of course it is a reference and there's no need to insert it back.